# How to persist data correctly in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to save the data of Windows Store app to the file system (local folder) on suspension of the the app. On start of the app the persisted data is loaded from the file system and displayed in the app. This is working fine until the user closes the app and immediately restarts the app (because the suspension of the first app instance isn't yet finished).

Now, I'm not sure whether

1. I have to persist the data in another way or
2. I can wait until any other instance of my app is completely suspended.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that after a close it take a few second before the suspending even is actually call and when the user restart, the previous instance of the app is killed so the suspending event is not even called and there is not much you can do to prevent that. 
The recommendation is to save data incrementally as anyway the suspended event only have 5 seconds to complete.

The other possibility is to make your app target windows 8.1 as this issue as been [fixed in windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263112.aspx):

> In Windows 8.1 Preview, if the user closes an app and then immediately
>   restarts it, the closed app is given up to five seconds to complete
>   its termination before it restarts. In Windows 8, the app terminates
>   immediately upon restart.